# rails rspec, erro no post :create, params require

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, create

Estou iniciando nos testes com rspec no RubyOnRails e estou tento um problema ao testar o create do meu controller:

```
it "creates lançamento" do
  post :create, params: attributes_for(:lancamento), format: :js, xhr: true
  expect(Lancamento.count).to eq(1)
end
```

Já criei a factory com o FactoryGirl.
O erro é o seguinte:

```
1) LancamentosController testa cadastro lançamento creates lançamento
 Failure/Error: params.require(:lancamento).permit(Lancamento.fields)

 ActionController::ParameterMissing:
   param is missing or the value is empty: lancamento
```

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda, obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faz

`post :create, params: { lancamento: attributes_for(:lancamento) }, format: :js, xhr: true`

e deve resolver teu problema.

E como sugestão, não programa em portugues. Motivos: http://www.akitaonrails.com/2008/07/31/tradu-o-por-que-voc-n-o-deve-codificar-em-portugu-s

Comment: Resolveu! obrigado, só que agora ele para no expect retornando 0.

Comment: Faz um debug no teu controller, pois ele pode ta caindo no else do save por alguma validação.

Comment: Exatamente, validação, vou arrumar a factory do lançamento. Obrigado!